# javascript create pro rated price calculator

Tags: javascript, date-arithmetic

I am trying to create a small js app to display the pro-rated price of a monthly subscription according to the current date. this is the plain english code that I have:

{

get todays date

check which month we are in

according to the month, calculate days remaining in the month

divide the price per month by total days in current month to get daily price

multiply daily price by days remaining in the current month

display pro-rated price

};

I am very new to javascript and have no clue how to go beyond getting todays date.

Comment: you should try it first...

Comment: When it comes to dates, have a look at http://momentjs.com

Comment: Calculation not difficult... search `javascript date object` for starters. Libraries like moment though do make it easier. Come back when you have made an effort and get stuck

Comment: Very good mwfire, I am looking at moments.js. Looks this is just what I need.

Comment: Its your homework try yourself first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this code may help you

```
function code(pricepermonth){


var dt = new Date();  
month = dt.getMonth();
day   = dt.getDate();
year  = dt.getFullYear();


if(month == 11)
var nextMonth = new Date(year+1,0,1);
else
var nextMonth = new Date(year,month+1,1);

var today = new Date(year,month,day);

var remain = (nextMonth.getTime() - today.getTime())/1000;  
remain = remain/(60*60*24);
totaldays = day+remain;     
var priceperday = pricepermonth/totaldays;

var remainingprice = priceperday*remain;
alert(remainingprice);
return remainingprice;
}

var pricepermonth = 50000;
code(pricepermonth);
```

Comment: Thank you SHIN this does exactly what I wanted to do. Since I am trying to learn javascript I will modify this code to work with moment.js. I still have to figure out how to display the answer on the page as opposed to an alert (please dont tell me).

Comment: var ans = code(pricepermonth);
 document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = ans;

Comment: <div id="mydiv"> on html </div>

Comment: Thanks again SHIN, I was able to use your answers to create this one page app [umcus.com/newark](http://umcus.com/newark)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simpler version that just looks at the number of days.  It counts today

```
function getProrate(monthlyPrice){
    var today = new Date();
    var totalDays = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 0).getDate();
    var daysLeft = (totalDays - today.getDate()) - 1; 

    var pricePerDay = monthlyPrice/totalDays;
    return daysLeft * pricePerDay;
}
```

It counts the tomorrow as the first day.